# How to evaluate the following indefinite integral? $\int e^{e^x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I stumbled across this question: what's the value of the following integral? $$\int e^{e^x}\mathrm dx.$$ Furthermore I was required to demonstrate. On wolfram I got the result $\operatorname{Ei}(e^x)$ but I don't know what is **exponential integral** neither what to do with it.
Thank you

Comment: There is no closed form for this integral - i.e. it's not an integral that we can write in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @Mathmo123 why is that? It's possible to calculate integral e^x dx, right?

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) you can see the definition of the exponential integral. The antiderivative of this function exists but it cannot be expressed in terms of other known functions (somebody demonstrated that). So, they define that integral to be a _new_ function with its own properties. It is pretty similar for all [Special Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_function).

Comment: For more information, see [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mathmo's answer makes clear, this isn't the kind of function for which you can find an elementary anti-derivative. But it is quite possible to *approximate* it: the Taylor series has a well-known form, and can be integrated term-by-term: $$e^{e^x-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{B_n}{n!}x^n
\implies \int e^{e^x}\,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(e\frac{B_{n-1}}{n!}\right)x^{n}+C$$ where $B_n$ is the $n$th [*Bell Number*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers). These integers are well understood; you can look up a table of them, or use the method in the Wikipedia link to find as many as you need. In principle, then, one may use this formula to approximate any definite integral of this function arbitrarily well. (In practice, of course, it could take a lot of terms and one may be well-advised to accelerate the convergence of the series somehow.)

Comment: @mathmo123 So it means there's no straight forward answer? Maybe This is a bit of a "trap" question to make you search for an answer.

Comment: @mxajd: I'd suggest looking at the problem you say pretty clearly, and seeing if they were asking for something more specific (say, what the integral over the entire real line is.)

Comment: nope, nothing specific. Just the original question.

Answer (score 5):

There are functions that are **integrable** - i.e. an integral exists and is well defined, but we cannot express the integral in terms of elementary functions. Yours is one example of this.

The crux is that we can come up with infinitely many different functions, but we only have a finite number of types elementary functions. As such, there are many functions where an integral exists and is well behaved, but doesn't its integral take the form of any function that we've given a name to.

One solution to this is to create new function names - the *Ei* function is an example of just that, and is defined to be $$\text{Ei}(x)=-\int_{-x}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}tdt$$

So that $$\frac d{dx}\mathrm{Ei}(x) = \frac{e^{x}}x$$We can then play with this function to define other integrals. For example, $$\begin{align}\frac d{dx}\text{Ei}(e^x) &= \frac{e^{e^x}}{e^x}\frac{d}{dx}e^x \qquad\text{(by the chain rule)}\\&=e^{e^x}\end{align}$$which is the example you were looking for.

Comment: Since every polynomial is an elementary function, there are *infinitely many* elementary functions.

Comment: @murray: One can perhaps read it as "finitely many _types_ of elementary functions." (Though I'm not completely sure that's true either.)

Comment: I agree the wording is a bit vague. I was going for a heuristic argument to explain why it is completely expected that some integrals can't be expressed in a closed form. Can you suggest a better way of phrasing it?

Comment: I've made the answer CW. Feel free to edit